# How to delete digits-only lines from a text file?

Tags: python-3.x

Let's say I have a text file which contains both alphanumerical values and only numerical values of length 10 digits line by line, like the one shown below:

```
abcdefgh
0123456789
edf6543jewjew
9876543219
```

I want to delete all the lines which contains only those random 10 digit numbers, i.e. expected output for the above example is the following:

```
abcdefgh
edf6543jewjew
```

**How can one do this in Python 3.x?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with open("yourTextFile.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open("yourTextFile.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        if not line.strip('\n').isnumeric():
            f.write(line)
        elif len(line.strip('\n')) != 10:
            f.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the input file, read all its lines, filter out the lines that contain only digits, then write the filtered lines back to a new file.

```py
import re

with open(input_file_path) as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

output_lines = [line for line in lines if not re.match(r'^[0-9]+$', line.strip('\n'))]

with open(output_file_path, 'w') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(output_lines))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import re
fh=open('Desktop\Python13.txt','r+')
content=fh.readlines()
fh.seek(0)
for line in content:
    if re.match(r'[0-9]{10}',line):
        content.remove(line)
fh.write(''.join(content))
fh.truncate()
fh.close()
```